# HTML <table> cells following a "complete" rowspan not working as expected

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to make a fairly simple table with a rowspan, and it works as expected.  However, the problem is with cells appearing *after* the all the spanned cells are resolved; they are not positioned where I think they should be.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <table width="100%" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="7">
                7 row
            </td>
            <td>
                1 row
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                1 row
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="5">
                5 row
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <i>This shouldn't be here, but below and aligned to the left side of the table</i>
            </td>
            <td>
                <i>This shouldn't be here, but below and aligned at the right side of the table</i>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's how it renders in Chrome and Firefox (I don't have the reputation to post inline images at Stack Overflow):

http://embernet.com/misc/rowspan.gif

Those two wordy cells really should be in the columns 1 and 2 that were already established, not as new columns 3 and 4.

The problem seems to come from me spanning rows that are never individually realized.  Keep in mind this is part of a larger, dynamically generated table that in some cases will show each of the 7 rows. I know someone will inevitably ask why I need to do this.

I don't see anything in the specs that suggests I cannot rowspan like this, so I'm hoping I'm just missing something obvious.

A JSFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/mLard575/

Comment: You only have four table rows to begin with. No what sense does spanning a cell over _seven_ of those _four_ rows make in your mind …?

Comment: can you draw or give an example what are you trying to accomplish. your gif link is not working

Comment: Sorry. GIF link is now working again.

Comment: CBroe: Ah, there's always someone asking "why" on Stack Overflow! This example is a really just a big reduction of a more complex table structure. There are actually two of these structures side-by-side, and sometimes there is no content on one side or the other, and sometime I load content later, through JavaScript.  It would be so much easier to have the 7 rows predefined ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are expecting. I give two possibilities as per my understanding.

Choose as per your requirements

**First Method:**

```css
table { 
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    padding: 20px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>

<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="7">7</td>
        <td> 1 </td>        
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td> 1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="5"> 5 </td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> 1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> 1 </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td> 1 </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td> 1 </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td> 1 </td>
        <td> 1 </td>
    </tr>
   
    </tbody>
</table>
 
</body>
```

**Second Method:**

```css
table { 
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    padding: 20px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>

<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="7">7</td>
        <td> 1 </td>        
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td> 1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> 1 </td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> 1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> 1 </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td> 1 </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td> 1 </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td> 1 </td>
        <td> 1 </td>
    </tr>
   
    </tbody>
</table>
 
</body>
```

If these two methods are not suited for you. Just explain little bit more with diagram example to update the code.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this, and your thoughtful suggestions.  I've got the GIF working, and I've answered CBroe's question of why I even need this in the comments of original post.

You two solutions both create new individual cells that occupy all 7 predefined rows, and thus render properly.  I'm getting the feeling that in HTML, rows cannot be spanned in reserve, as I'm attempting to do.